# <ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8> because of some characters in XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to parse the XML file and feed the data to database in Ruby. Here is where its failing :

```
<info> <![CDATA[
         interface allow user to vary parameters in referenced models
         under certain conditions. 
         If a top model is referencing another model, ***�one and only one�*** of the following is true: 

      ]]> </info>
```

I have highlighted the text where its failing to parse and throws me this error.Is there a workaround for this ??

I am currently using `.encode("UTF-8",:invalid => :replace,undef: :replace, replace: '')` ... but the invalid characters are not replaced !

its failing at `doc = REXML::Document.new file` before even entering to check individual elements within the XML

Comment: You corrupted the UTF8-encoded bytes before reading it into a string.  You need to fix that code.

Comment: this is the code am using to fetch the cdata ....file["file_comments"]=testfile.elements["info"].cdatas.join.strip ... please suggest me how to fix it ?

Comment: Where are you reading the bytes?

Comment: here ..... testfile.elements["info"].cdatas.join.strip

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but that looks like strings, not bytes.